# Excel: creating an array with n times a constant

Tags: arrays, excel

I have been looking around for a while but unable to find an answer to my question.

**In Excel, what compact formula can I use to create an array made up of a single element repeated `n` times, where `n` is an input (potentially hard-coded)?**

For example, something that would look like this (the formula below *does not* work but gives an idea of what I am looking for):

```
{={"Constant"}*3}
```

*Note: I am not looking for a VBA-based solution.*

Comment: What's wrong with =A1*3 in a cell that's not A1?

Comment: @jake.toString With that formula you are multiplying numbers, that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could concatenate 1:n empty cells to the "Constant" to create a string array having n items "Constant":

`"Constant"&INDEX(XFD:XFD,1):INDEX(XFD:XFD,3)`

There 3 is n.

Used in Formula

`=INDEX("Constant"&INDEX(XFD:XFD,1):INDEX(XFD:XFD,3),0)`

`Evaluate Formula` shows that it works:

[image]

Here column `XFD` is used because in most cases this column will be empty and a column which is guaranteed to be empty is needed for this solution.

If used

`"Constant"&T(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,3)))`

`=INDEX("Constant"&T(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,3))),0)`

the need of an empty column disappears. The function `ROW` returns numbers but the `T` returns an empty string if its parameter is not text. So empty strings will be concatenated for each 1:3 (n).

Thanks to @MacroMarc for the hint.

Comment: Sure Axel, but there is no need to run risk of anything in XFD, could just say: `="hello world" & T(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A, 4, 1)))`

Comment: @MacroMarc Nice concise method of generating arrays.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**  Reading @AxelRichter answer, I see I should also indicate that the formulas below assume **Constant** is a number.  If **Constant** is text, then this solution will not work.

Volatile:

```
=ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & Repts))/ROW(INDIRECT("1" & ":" & Repts)) * Constant
```

non-Volatile:

```
=ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,Repts,1))/ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,Repts,1))*Constant
```

If

```
Constant = 14
Repts = 3
```

then

```
Result = {14;14;14}
```

The first part of the formulas create an array of 1's repeated `Repts` times.  Then we multiply that array by Constant to get the desired result.

And after reading **@MacroMarc**'s comment, the following non-volatile formula shouyld also work for numbers:

```
=(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,Repts))>0)*Constant
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "Constant" is literally text, @Axel Richter answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Glad you have a solution.  One caveat, with his solution, you need to ensure that column `XFD` is empty, as it is concatenating the contents of those cells with `Constant`

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: Nevertheless this answer should be here for the case someone wants this using Constant to be a number.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks. I agree and am planning to leave it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, that is how I would do it for nums

Answer (score 3):

Using SEQUENCE with a step of 0 is a much cleaner way to make an array of constants. You can choose whether you want rows or columns (or both!) as well.

`=SEQUENCE(Repts,1,Constant,0)`

Comment: This is useful to know, but only works for numbers - not generic objects.

Answer (score 3):

This might be simpler.  If what you want is number, then:

```
=SEQUENCE(25,1,67,0)
```

where 25 and 1 are the number of rows and columns of your array, the first 0 is the starting point of the sequence, I took 67 as an example of the constant value you want to replicate, and the 2nd 0 is the increment.  An increment of 0 obviously keeps the same value in the whole are.
If what you want is a text, it's a bit more complicated but not that much:

```
=LEFT("text",SEQUENCE(25,1,10,0))
```

So the `SEQUENCE` creates an array 25x1 with 10 all over, then by using it as the number of characters to retain for the `LEFT` function gives you "text" repeated all over the 25x1 array.  The only requirement is that the 10 be larger than the length of your text.

Comment: This solved my problem. Also by supplementing the second solution with a reference to the text and using LEN  you can avoid defining a specific length

Answer (score 2):

I will generally use a sequence (like Claire (above) said). But if you want to provide an output of text objects, I would do it this way:

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(A1,A2,1,0),A3)
```

Where:

- A1 has the number of rows
- A2 has the number of columns
- A3 has the thing you want repeated into an array

The sequence will create a matrix of 1's, which the `IF` statement will default to the `TRUE` expression (being the contents of A3).

So, if you wanted a vertical list of 3 items that says "Constant", this would do it:

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(3,,1,0),"Constant")
```

If you would prefer it be arranged horizontally instead of vertically, just amend the `SEQUENCE` function:

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(,3,1,0),"Constant")
```

Comment: You don't even need the other arguments of `SEQUENCE()`. You can just do `=IF(SEQUENCE(3),"Constant")`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
REPT("Constant", SEQUENCE(3,1,1,0))
```

Or, if the reference is to a dynamic array:

```
REPT("Constant", SEQUENCE(A1#,1,1,0))
```

The dynamic array spills, and has your constant repeated one time.

Comment: This is nice but I would not it is a vertical result, and you can use`SEQUENCE(1,3,1,0)` to get a horizontal result.

Answer (score 1):

Well you even do not have to specify start of sequence, only number of rows (or columns - depending what you need) and the IF statement will be TRUE, FALSE is only when it equals 0 in all other cases (even negative number) it is TRUE. You can use shorter version:

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(Repts),Constant)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `MAKEARRAY` function which is available in Excel 365 version.

The following formula generates an array with 100 rows and 1 column, where each cell contains 'Text':

```
=MAKEARRAY(100, 1, LAMBDA(r, c, "Text"))
```

You can also do calculations with the row index `r` and the column index `c`.

I performed a speed test with VBA and evaluated that function 100'000 times. It is considerably slower compared to using:

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(100), "Text")
```

So if performance is crucial rather use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options you're working with an **array**, as opposed to a single constant.

### Collated order

Use this formula if you need to repeat **an array** n times:

```
=LET(
ary, {"Constant1", "Constant2", "Constant3"},
repts, 2,
arySize, COUNTA(ary),
totalRows, arySize * repts,
MAKEARRAY(totalRows, 1,
  LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(ary, MOD(r-1, arySize) + 1)))
)

---- Returns ----
Constant1
Constant1
Constant2
Constant2
Constant3
Constant3
```

### Grouped order

Use this formula if you need to repeat **each value in an array** n times:

```
=LET(
ary, {"Constant1", "Constant2", "Constant3"},
repts, 2,
arySize, COUNTA(ary),
totalRows, arySize * repts,
MAKEARRAY(totalRows, 1,
  LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(ary, QUOTIENT(r-1, repts) + 1))
))

---- Returns ----  
Constant1
Constant2
Constant3
Constant1
Constant2
Constant3
Constant1
Constant2
Constant3
```

### Notes

These work with `ary` as an array constant or a one-dimensional range of cells (i.e., all in the same row or in the same column).

These also work the original request from @daneel-olivaw, which was a single value within an array; i.e., `{"Constant"}` returns `{"Constant"; "Constant"; "Constant"}`. The advantage of this approach is that OP can now add additional values to the original array constant, if desired.