# Excel: create an array with n occurences of a value x

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to create an excel array with n occurences of an x value, n and x being vectors.

Desired behaviour :

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      occurences     |       value      |      result      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         4        |    {4;4;4;1;1}   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

This is a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526178/excel-creating-an-array-with-n-times-a-constant) one, except that I want one more dimension. I'm not interested in a VBA answer, I'm looking for a formula.

I've tried playing around with index and concatenation like in the answer to the previously linked question but with no luck until now.

This result will be used in a bigger formula that will sum the m greatest values (I already have that part figured and working, the m value is irrelevant here). You can consider this question as if the occurences are the storage amounts, and I want the sum of the m greatest individual values.

Comment: What do you plan to do with this array? What's the end goal?

Comment: Are you using Excel 365? If so, do you want the result to Spill?

Comment: Yes I'm using Excel 365, and I don't really want the result to spill, it's just a part of a bigger formula. I'll edit the question to better describe the endgame of this formula.

Comment: From the extra bit that you've added to the question, maybe there's a more direct way of doing this without expanding the values? Suppose you wanted the sum of the top four values in your data, it's 4*3 + 1*1 = 13 (ignoring the last '1') which you can get just from the values and the occurrences. Could be a bit of an XY problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: @TomSharpe maybe ? Your answer below works for me, but for the sake of understanding, how would you compute this 13 just from m=4 and values/occurences ?

Comment: I've been giving a bit of thought to this and eventually realised it's just the tiered rate problem in disguise. In simple terms, what if the price when you buy up to 3 items is $4 each and the price for the next 2 items is $1 each ? If you buy 4 such items, the cost is $13. See https://www.excelcampus.com/modeling/calculate-commissions-with-tiered-rate-structure/ It might be worth posting a general question under the heading 'Sum of top n items from frequencies' because a quick search hasn't come up with any previous answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach in O365:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(A1:A3),1,0),
MMULT(N(ROW(A1:A3)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A3))),A1:A3)-A1:A3))
```

where you're looking up the row number of the output array in the running total of the input counts.

[image]

I think it could be modified to work over an arbitrary range but would then be a fairly long formula.

If the inputs aren't in the sheet but coming from an array formula, then still possible but it would be a very long formula.

Comment: Thank you ! By changing the `B:B` to `B1:B3` to make it work even if the data isn't on first rows, and filling the occurence vector with zeros until the max possible size I was able to do what I wanted :)

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was quite what you wanted, but glad it worked for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,SEQUENCE(3,,4,0),SEQUENCE(2,,1,0)) & "</s></t>","//s")
```

will return:    `{4;4;4;1;1}`  which can be used as part of a larger formula.

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure : first I'm on Excel 365 and filterxml isn't available here. Then, the occurence and values vectors can be of various length, so a solution with manual imput for each sequence won't work I'm afraid.

Comment: @Yvonnig You are probably running on a Mac. So, no, you don't have that function since it requires elements of the Windows OS.  If you have a known, maximum number of elements, that could be added to the formula, since `TEXTJOIN` can ignore blanks; but if the maximum number of pairs is large or unknown, I'd suggest a helper column (for those not running on Mac or Excel online).